# Android Service.startForeground does NOT respect notification id uniqueness

Tags: android, service, notifications, unique

[Service.startForeground()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29) vs [NotificationManager.notify()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#notify%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29), give different behaviors.

When using **notify** with two different notification ids, 2 notifications are created - **Good**.

When doing the same with **startForground**, one notification overrides the other - **Bad**.

Tested device: Nexus S(2.3.6) and Asus Transformer (4.0.3).

Any ideas how I can run an Important (foreground) service that can have several (dynamic number) notifications?

Comment: Happens on the Asus transformer (Android 4.0.3) as well.

Comment: Opened an issue: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=28011

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not the best solution, but you can always just "reassign" a notification to a dismissed notification ID. For example, say you start Process 1 (foreground) and then Process 2 (using NotificationManager). When Process 1 ends, dismiss the notification for Process 2 and update the foreground notification for Process 1 to actually now show the progress for Process 2.

That way you don't have to call `stopForeground()` and `startForeground()`, which may allow the service to be killed in between (haven't actually checked that's true, though).

Comment: Vaskevich, what if only single process is involved in this context? And can you just elaborate on reassigning the notification to dismissed... ?

Comment: My understand is it doesn't matter, since when you call `stopForeground()`, Android can now kill your service. I feel like I elaborated enough; please just re-read the second sentence a few times!