# How do I get an Android service to broadcast an intent every few seconds?

Tags: android, service, asynchronous

If I've created a service, how do I get it to broadcast an intent every X seconds? I remember seeing a snippet of code along the lines

```
startThreadDelayed( new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        doStuff();
        sendBroadcast(messageIntent);
        startThreadDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
}, 1000);
```

Unfortunatelly I'm not sure of either the class name, or the exact method name, for whatever is looping. Just a name would point me in the right direction of searching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `Handler.postDelayed`. [Here is the documentation.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29)

For Example

```
Handler h = new Handler();
YourClass yourRunnable = new YourClass();
h.postDelayed(youRunnable,1000);


public class YourClass implements Runnable{
    public void run(){
    doStuff();
    sendBroadcast(messageIntent);
    if(running)
        h.postDelayed(youRunnable,1000);
}
```

here running is a flag better keep it as volatile boolean. So that by changing it's value you can stop the repeatition.

Comment: Thank you, it WAS a Handler I was imagining.

Comment: I have updated my answer with an example.. But there are other ways to do this too

Comment: I'll take a better way to do things too, if you have any links!

Comment: I posted the answer because I think it is the better way .. Other than that you can use Timer or Thread.sleep by using same logic. But if I were you I would use Handler

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was hoping. I'm not sure if this can be done with an anonymous runnable, yet (e.g. when it's done it would .postDelayed itself).

Comment: you can create annonymouse Runnable within postDelayed. But at that case that will create a new instance everytimee your postdelayed is called.

Answer (score 3):

You may consider using [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).
By using it you can trigger any `Intent` one-time or recurring with any schedule.

For example:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, YourReceiver.class);
PendingIntent broadcast = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i, 0);

long first = System.currentTimeInMillis(); // now
long interval = 5 * 1000; // every 5 seconds
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, first, interval, broadcast);
```

Comment: This wasn't what I was thinking, but it was still a great answer :)