# Notification of ForegroundService cancel not working

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications, foreground-service

I have a forground service, started by a binding activity. When the activity forast created the service, if user initiates the service, it will make it forground by calling below code

```
public void makeForgroundService() {
    notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
            sessionId, new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);
    notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("My Test Service ")
            .setContentText("Service now Running")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.newicon)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    // notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
    // getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notify_id = sessionId;
    Log.e(TAG,"making foreGrounf : sessionId = "+String.valueOf(notify_id));
    startForeground(notify_id, notificationBuilder.build());
    isForeground = true;
}
```

Now when activity is launched again , it is binding to the serive, (as already service is running and is forground) .  Now i wanna cancel the notification, tried it on getService call, but not working !

```
@Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        // Log.e(TAG, "Inside onServiceConnected");
        myService = ((MyService.MyBinder) service).getService();
        if(myService.isForeground){

                    Log.e(TAG,"From Activity,removing notification : "+myService.notify_id);

                    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    nm.cancel(myService.notify_id);

        }
    }
```

## Note

I dont want to `stopForground` of MyService. Just need to **hide or cancel** the notification.

### Update:

If stopForground is the only way, will stopForground let the service liable to be killed during the activity is in foreground ? Can i set StartForground at onDestroy of activity? Is it a (**right**)way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

You can send a message to your service (passing some parameter in the extras) in order to stop the foreground state.

Then in your service the only thing you need to call is to `stopForeground(true)` and the notification will be removed.

Comment: I don't want to `stopForground` . I only want to hide notification, if the activity is available

Comment: You cannot have a foreground service without notification.

Comment: Guessing notificationId should be same while cancelling.

Comment: Calling `stopForeground` wont stop your service, it will just remove the "foreground" state and the icon. Android will NOT allow you to have a foreground service without icons.

Comment: @VnyKumar, it's same!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9927938/android-service-startforeground-does-not-respect-notification-id-uniqueness?lq=1

Comment: @VnyKumar, in that post, what they mean by `re-assigning`? If re-assignign is calling NotifiactionManager.notify(reAssignedId,notification), what purpose it will serve? Does it what teh answer am i supposed to be heard?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the android services documention, you cannot have a foreground service without a notification. The point is that if a service is going to be resource intensive the user has a right to know.

[Service docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)